# Where to place widgets in Yii2 application

Tags: yii2, widget, yii2-widget

I'm using Yii2 to create my application. I also like to use the widget feature, but I'm not sure, what is the best practice for the widget code location. The Yii2 directory-structure provides 2 directories:

1. @app/components
2. @app/widgets

The location "2." (@app/widgets) sounds like the best location for widgets. But, the [Yii2 documentation for widgets](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-widgets) used the location "1." (@app/components)

So my question: what is the right place for own widgets?

Comment: I voted to close the question as opinion-based. There is no strict specification where the widgets should be placed. Personally, I would vote for location 2. As widgets are part of view in MVC architecture. It's better to keep them separated from other components responsible for business logic.

Comment: "There is no strict specification where the widgets should be placed. " Is this the case and the intention of the yii2 framework? Than this could be the answer. The point is, that I cant find any Information about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I put it in `@app/components/*.`

There I also put

```
@app/components/widgets/*
@app/components/helpers/*
@app/components/validators/*
@app/components/otherComponent/*
@app/components/MyActiveRecord.php
@app/components/MyController.php
```

and other components of my application

Comment: But, what is your decision based on?

Comment: Actually there is no official recommendation for this.
I do it this way because I know that the elements in @app/components are developed by me and I don't mess up the rest of the folders that are recommended by Yii.